# Set value of Viewstate from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on asp.net application. Where for a page I have to clear the value of the controls(like textbox and dropdownlist,etc), also i have to remove the value of a ViewState. Initailly i was doing it from codebehind, so o problem was there. But now the problem arise when i tried reset the value of controls using client side , say

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtTextBox.ClientID %>').value ='';
```

but the problem i am facing is that i cannot set the viewstate value from clientside.
my i have to clear to viewstate one is a simple variable say ViewState["NameOfUser"],and another one is converting a datatable into viewstate say,

```
ViewState["dataTable"] = dt;
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: If you change the element the javacode included by microsoft will change the viewstate on submit.

Comment: @Rahul is it not clear from the title ??

Comment: You shouldn't modify viewstate, as that will give you an error when posting back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can not assign value in client side.

1. Either you have to pass it through hidden field while submitting form or
2. Call ajax from javascript and access the ViewState server side.

Comment: any sample or reference link will be very much helpful.

Comment: do you have an access to ViewState property when doing ajax call which is static method?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way via ajax request:

Credits: https://forums.asp.net/t/1991868.aspx?Set+value+of+Viewstate+from+Javascript+or+Jquery

```
ViewState["dataTable"] = dt;
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            //clear datatable
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/ClearDataTable",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('cleared');
                }
            });
            //clear other values.....
            //............
        });
    })
</script>
```

On codebehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void ClearDataTable()
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Session["datatable"] = null;
    }
```

Hope that it helps!